Unable to run .sh and .ps1 file with Python
I learned that you can write scripts and run multiple commands by executing a .sh or .ps1 file in Bash and PowerShell respectively. However, when I run my files I get the same error (both in Bash and PowerShell) and I am unable to understand why.
Python version I'm running is 3.11.4
OS: Win11
Script I'm trying to run is:
python3 -c "print(1)"

Command I'm executing
In PowerShell:
./test.ps1

In Bash:
./test.sh

Error message I receive is:
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

When I run it with python, for example:
py test.ps1

Or
py test.sh

I receive the following error:
  File "D:\python\testing\test.ps1", line 1
    python3 -c "print(1)"
               ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The fact that it shows the contents of the file it means it is running it, but I'm unable to figure out what's the problem with the syntax.

Works for me. Can you [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?

This exact error message will be show if you try to call python from inside Python itself.

You're running the command in a Python REPL. This is evident by the error you get - it's treating the command you wrote as Python code, which is not valid syntax. You need to run that command in a shell. Open your regular, plain-old terminal and run the command in there.

I opened the normal terminal and ran the command "py test.sh" as well as "py test.ps1" and threw the same error.

Thanks for the extra context. You're trying to using Python to execute PowerShell code. Python can only execute Python code. To run the PowerShell script from a PowerShell terminal, just run ./test.ps1.

I ran the commands:
PS D:\python\testing> set-executionpolicy unrestricted -scope process
PS D:\python\testing> ./test.ps1
And received the error:
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Try using py instead of python3 in your PowerShell script e.g. py -c "print(1)"

Thank you it worked. I used py.exe in my PowerShell script. E.g. py.exe -c "print(1)"
